# pdfpages 2016 vs. pdfpages 2002

Tags: pdfpages

Using package pdfpages from 2016 (pdfpages 2016/04/19 v0.5f) with *addtotoc*-option yields problems which do not arise with pdfpages-Package from 2002 (pdfpages 2002/10/01 v0.2k).  Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\includepdf[pages=1-12,nup=2x2,addtotoc={
1,section,1,Filme auf Festplatte U,U,
1,subsection,2,U001,U001,
7,subsection,2,U007,U007
}]{input.pdf}
\end{document}
```

1. Using 2002-version all works fine: Apart from table of Contents there are 3 Sheets of Output, each containing 4 pages of Input and correct links in the table of Contents.
2. Using the 2016-version of pdfpages gives the following Output (for the above example):
   Table of Contents
   First output-sheet contains input-page 1 in upper left corner, rest is blank.
   Second output-sheet White space in upper left corner and then page 2-4 at correct Positions.
   Third output-sheet contains input-pages 5-7, lower right Corner is blank
   and fourth Output-sheet contains only page 8 in lower right Corner.
   Rest is oK.

Obviously there is a pagebreak after each entry from *addtotoc*-Option which doesn't makes sense - in my honest opinion.
The above example should work with any input.pdf containing at least 12 pages.
Thanks for help, N. Klingen

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, add a minimal example.

Comment: I think an MWE would be helpful. And perhaps a pointer to where the 2002 package may be found. What version is the 2002 one? It seems the most recent is 'only' `0.5f`.... But I don't have a copy of the earlier versions anymore.

Comment: The change is much more recent than 2002. Using my archive if TL releases, I am fine with the ('final update') TL'14 one (`pdfpages 2013/08/25 v0.4v`) but not with the TL'15 one (`pdfpages 2015/09/18 v0.5d`). I'll try to get a diff for this.

Comment: The issue seems to appear between v0.4w and v0.4x (https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty?r1=36894&r2=37333)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears between v0.4x (2015-05-11) and v0.4w (2015-04-15): the TeX Live SVN [shows us a diff](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty?r1=36894&r2=37333). This is not a 'simple' change, and with no change log or other info it's not immediately obvious where the problem is. As a temporary work-around, I suggest using the [latest working version of the code](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty?revision=31518&view=markup) from the TeX Live SVN. (Version v0.4w seems to have an unrelated issue which means I'd go with v0.4v here.) For a long-term fix, this needs attention from the package author: I have reported it by email.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I always found it hard go obtain older versions.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Depends on the package and the timeframe. The TeX Live SVN is good for the past ~10 years, before that there are yearly snapshots. For LaTeX itself, our SVN goes back a _long_ way ...

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the thourough Analysis of the Problem.  As work-around I used the old Version of pdfpages, it worked fine, but I thought it might be useful for the community to know of this Problem because pdfpages is an extremely useful  package.

Comment: @Joseph Wright and the package-maintainer: I just updated MiKTeX which contains  pdfpages 2016/12/11 v0.5g. Now my problem is completely solved, my old source files work as ever before. Many Thanks to all those involved in updating the system!!